# Cast from uint8_t pointer to uint32_t integer compilation error

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Following error shows while compilation process:

```
aes.c:267:35: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
    HWREG(AES_DMAC_CH0_EXTADDR) = (uint32_t)pui8MsgIn;
```

The lines 275-276:

```
// base address of the input data in ext. memory
HWREG(AES_DMAC_CH0_EXTADDR) = (uint32_t)pui8MsgIn;
```

pui8MsgIn is type of **uint8_t ***.

HWREG macro looks like this:

```
#define HWREG(x)                                                              \
        (*((volatile uint32_t *)(x)))
```

I am not experienced in C and its pointers, but presumably I could resolve it by changing **uint32_t** cast to **uintptr_t**. Is it correct?

I want to confirm that, because **uintptr_t** seems to not have any size in it's name contrary to **uint32_t**.

Comment: Yes. uintptr_t instead of uint32_t should fix it.

Comment: I'm guessing the hardware is 32-bit. I believe this is the issue: `HWREG(AES_DMAC_CH0_EXTADDR) = (uint32_t)pui8MsgIn;` I suspect you need the right hand side to be `(uint32_t*)(void*)pui8MsgIn;` to avoid the error and subsequent warnings under modern compilers, like GCC and Clang. Clang usually needs the extra intermediate cast to avoid additional warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> presumably I could resolve it by changing `uint32_t` cast to `uintptr_t`.
>   Is it correct?

Yes.  `uintptr_t` is specified to be an unsigned integer type wide enough to accommodate the result of the conversion of any pointer to an integer.

> I want to confirm that, because uintptr_t seems to not have any size
>   in it's name contrary to uint32_t.

That's the whole point (no pun intended).  C does not specify how big a pointer is, and in fact that varies between implementations.  You can't specify a particular size in the type name if you must accommodate all implementations' pointers.

Comment: Details: "C does not specify how big a pointer is" includes that a pointer may be wider than all integers types. Types `(u)intptr_t` are optional although commonly implemented.  Also "... accommodate the result of the conversion of any _object_ pointer to an integer.".  Perhaps not so with function pointers.